# Clear browser cache after publish

Tags: asp.net, caching

I tell them my problem. I have a fairly large site, where there are frequent changes. The same is made. Net F 3.5.

My big problem is that every time I make a rise in production I have to send a mail to all the people who use that site to clean your browser history. As it begins to have the same malfunction as it mixes the previous web with the latest version uploaded.

Is there any way to force a refresh of the page to a raise? but without disabling the cache? Since layers increases are 1 per month and cache for the size of the web is very useful.

Greetings and thanks to all

Comment: Hi, you need to commit to this proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish and then you can ask your question on the beta :-)

Comment: Please ask questions in english language

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/400718/how-to-make-sure-clients-update-their-browser-cache-when-my-website-is-updated